# famous: scrollview within scrollview

Tags: scrollview, famo.us

I'm trying to create a layout (using famous.js) similar to the BBC News native app; a vertical ScrollView, within which are numerous horizontal ScrollViews. I've got both 'working' to the extent that everything renders and the horizontal scrollers work perfectly. My issue is that the vertical scroll event won't fire if the user swipes a surface within a horizontal ScrollView. If i touch an area outside the horizontal scrollers, the vertical scroller will do its job and scroll... vertically

Does anyone know what i'm missing? I have a feeling that a RenderNode may be needed, but have had no luck so far. I'm just getting to grips with Famous. What i've seen so far is amazing, but not being able to figure this out is really getting to me...

Uber thanks in advance if anyone can help...

```
    /*globals define*/
    define(function(require, exports, module) {

        // import dependencies
        var Modifier           = require('famous/core/Modifier');
        var Engine             = require('famous/core/Engine');
        var Surface            = require('famous/core/Surface');
        var HeaderFooterLayout = require('famous/views/HeaderFooterLayout');
        var Scrollview         = require('famous/views/Scrollview');
        var ContainerSurface   = require('famous/surfaces/ContainerSurface');

        var mainContext = Engine.createContext();

        var layout = new HeaderFooterLayout({
            headerSize: 50,
            footerSize: 50
        });

        // create app header and add to layout
        var appHeader = new ContainerSurface({
            size: [undefined, 50],
            classes: ['app-header']
        });
        appHeader.add(new Surface({
            size: [undefined, 50],
            content: 'Site Name',
            classes: ['app-header__title'],
            properties: {
                lineHeight: '50px',
                textAlign: 'center'
            }
        }));
        layout.header.add(appHeader);

        // create page container surface
        var page = new ContainerSurface({
            properties: {
                top: '0'
            }
        });

        // returns a horizontal ScrollView containing 
        function createCategory() {
            var categoryScroll = new Scrollview({
                direction: 0,
            });
            var surfaces = [];
            categoryScroll.sequenceFrom(surfaces);
            for (var i = 0, temp; i < 7; i++) {
                var temp = new Surface({
                    size: [128, 128],
                    content: 'surface' + (i + 1),
                    properties: {
                        backgroundColor: '#fff',
                        borderColor: '#303030',
                        borderStyle: 'solid',
                        borderWidth: '0px',
                        borderRightWidth: '4px',
                        borderLeftWidth: '4px'
                    }
                });
                temp.pipe(categoryScroll);
                surfaces.push(temp);
            }
            return categoryScroll; 
        }

        // returns a vertical page scroll
        function createPageScroll() {

            // create array of horizontal ScrollViews
            categories = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                categories.push(createCategory());
            };

            var pageScroll = new Scrollview();
            var surfaces = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                temp = new ContainerSurface({
                    size: [window.innerWidth, 136],
                });
                temp.add(categories[i]);
                surfaces.push(temp);
                pageScroll.sequenceFrom(surfaces);
                temp.pipe(pageScroll);
            };

            return pageScroll;
        }

        layout.content.add(createPageScroll());
        mainContext.add(layout);

    });
```

Comment: I figured it out. No RenderNode needed. I had to do temp.pipe(pageScroll) just before temp.pipe(categoryScroll). Also moved pageScroll into global scope. Hope this helps someone...

Answer (score 4):

I see you figured it out, but I thought I would post a clean working example for anyone that needed a starting point.. So here it is..

To answer the question, Yes, you needed to pipe your events from the surfaces to each of the scrollviews

```
var Engine              = require("famous/core/Engine");
var Surface             = require("famous/core/Surface");
var View                = require("famous/core/View");
var Scrollview          = require("famous/views/Scrollview");
var ContainerSurface    = require("famous/surfaces/ContainerSurface");

var context = Engine.createContext();

var surfaces1 = [];
var surfaces2 = [];

var scrollers = [];

scroll_v_cont = new ContainerSurface({
    size:[300,300],
    properties: { overflow: 'hidden' }
});

var scroll_v = new Scrollview({ direction: 1 });

scroll_v.sequenceFrom(scrollers);

scroll_v_cont.add(scroll_v);

var scroll_h1_cont = new ContainerSurface({
    size:[300,300],
    properties: {overflow: 'hidden'}
});


var scroll_h1 = new Scrollview({ direction: 0});

scroll_h1.sequenceFrom(surfaces1);

scroll_h1_cont.add(scroll_h1);


var scroll_h2_cont = new ContainerSurface({
    size:[300,300],
    properties: { overflow: 'hidden'}
})


var scroll_h2 = new Scrollview({ direction: 0})

scroll_h2.sequenceFrom(surfaces2);

scroll_h2_cont.add(scroll_h2);

scrollers.push(scroll_h1_cont);
scrollers.push(scroll_h2_cont);

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var surface1 = new Surface({
         content: "Surface: " + (i + 1),
         size: [300, 300],
         properties: {
             backgroundColor: "hsl(" + (i * 360 / 8) + ", 100%, 50%)",
             lineHeight: "200px",
             textAlign: "center"
         }
    });

    surface1.pipe(scroll_v);
    surface1.pipe(scroll_h1);
    surfaces1.push(surface1);

    var surface2 = new Surface({
         content: "Surface: " + (i + 1),
         size: [300, 300],
         properties: {
             backgroundColor: "hsl(" + (i * 360 / 8 + (360 / 8)*4) + ", 100%, 50%)",
             lineHeight: "200px",
             textAlign: "center"
         }
    });

    surface2.pipe(scroll_v);
    surface2.pipe(scroll_h2);
    surfaces2.push(surface2);

};

context.add(scroll_v_cont);
```

Comment: Why do you embed the scroller in a container? Only to set size and overflow? Can't you use a modifier for this?

Comment: @markmarijnissen That is a good question.. The overflow example I had seen somewhere else. I assume your way would work.. But to add the scroller to a SequentialLayout, wouldn't you need to add each the modifier and the surface to a RenderNode instance, then add that to the sequence?.. Maybe that's just the way to do it.. I am looking to learn too!

Answer (score 1):

the famous-flex FlexScrollView supports vertical & horizontal scrolling restrictions when embedding one scrollview in another. It is described in more detail at the bottom of the FlexScrollView tutorial:

https://github.com/IjzerenHein/famous-flex/blob/master/tutorials/FlexScrollView.md