# Is It possible to implement Horizontal Scrolling using famo.us?

Tags: famo.us

The [famo.us tutorials](http://famo.us/examples/0.2.0/surfaces/containersurface/example) shows how to use a ScrollView which doesn't seem to provide a horizontal scrolling method.

So I was wondering how do I implement horizontal scrolling for my [famo.us app](http://mbasim.me) (my personal website).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. To enable Horizontal scrolling you simply pass the direction option to the Scrollview constructor..

```
var scrollview = new Scrollview({
    direction: Utility.Direction.X
});
```

Utility.Direction.X actually is a pretty way of saying 0. So this will work as well..

```
var scrollview = new Scrollview({
    direction: 0
});
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Okay great! Now do I need two scrollViews for horizontal and vertical or can I specify both somehow?

Comment: Currently the way Scrollview is implemented, you can only specify one direction. But check out my answer here for scrollview within scrollview! :) Good luck! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144982/famous-scrollview-within-scrollview/23145785#23145785